# How do I select records from Sqlite table partially grouped?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a table like this. And I want to select `Fruits` grouped together based on the `group_id` but not the `Vegetables` and `Nuts`. For `Vegetable` and `Nuts`, I want them all.

```
  group_id  name                type
    -----------------------------------
    1        Green Apple          Fruit 
    1        Red Apple            Fruit
    1        Blue Apple           Fruit
    2        Green Peas           Vegetable
    2        Snow Peas            Vegetable
    2        Another Pea          Vegetable
    3        Ground Nut           Nuts
    3        Peanut               Nuts
    4        Carrot               Vegetable
```

This is how I have tried right now. This works well, but I want to know if there is any simpler approach.

```
select * from Grocessaries GROUP BY group_id HAVING type in ('Fruit', 'Drinks')     

UNION all

select * from Grocessaries where type in ('Vegetable', 'Nuts')
```

Basically, I want the result something like this (grouped Fruits and all Vegetables and Nuts)

```
group_id  name                type
        -----------------------------------
        1        Green Apple          Fruit 
        2        Green Peas           Vegetable
        2        Snow Peas            Vegetable
        2        Another Pea          Vegetable
        3        Ground Nut           Nuts
        3        Peanut               Nuts
        4        Carrot               Vegetable
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on logic? Why Blue and Red apples were filtered out but Snow Peas stayed in your desired output?

Comment: In the first query `GROUP BY group_id` make no sence because you didn't use any aggregate function..

Comment: It looks like you're mixing grouping and ordering

Comment: Order is not a problem for me. I've removed the ordering part from the query. I just care about the grouping part.

Comment: Why `Green Apple Fruit`  and not `Red Apple Fruit` or `Blue Apple Fruit`?

Comment: @peterm I have a similar requirement and it may not make sense in this example, but in app it make sense. I can't come up with a perfect example that can explain my requirement. But this is exactly what I want.

Comment: In the UI, when you choose either one of the apple, we have an option to view the other apples that are grouped with the first one. So it doesn't matter which Apple I get in the grouping query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're handling Fruits (and Drinks) specially in the UI the actual name returned for them isn't that important so you could do

```
SELECT group_id,
  CASE type
    WHEN 'Fruits' THEN 'Fruits' -- or whatever you want to display
    WHEN 'Drinks' THEN 'Drinks'
    ELSE name
  END NameGrouped,
  type
FROM Grocessaries
GROUP BY group_id, NameGrouped, type
```